# x86-64 Assembly Based Indexed Addressing & Segfaults

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, x86-64

I'm having trouble with the following assembly code.

```
.section .rodata
.globl main
main:
enter $(8*10),$0

mov $10, %rax

mov -48(%rbp), %r10
mov $1, %r11
mov %rax, (%r10, %r11, 8)

main_return:
leave
ret
```

Here's what I think, the code I wrote is doing, but I might be wrong.

1. Create a new stack frame with 10 (64-bit) locations I can potentially use.
2. Load the immediate value of 10 into the `%rax` register
3. Store the value in `%rax` into `%r10+(%r11)*8` (in other words `-40(%rbp)`)

For some reason, the code produces a segmentation fault when compiled and run using `gcc`. However, when the immediate value of `$0`, or `$2` are loaded, the segmentation fault disappears. I'm trying to understand why this is the case.

The command I'm using to compile the assembly code is: `gcc code.s -o code` and I'm running the program by simply executing `./code`.

Comment: The `enter` instruction is slow.  Compilers use `push %rbp` / `mov %rsp, %rbp` because it's significantly faster.  `leave` is not too bad; gcc still uses it in some cases instead of `mov %rbp, %rsp` / `pop %rbp`.  But if `%rsp` is already pointing in the right place, it just uses `pop %rbp`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the tip! I'm actually creating a compiler rather than writing the assembly by hand. I'll look into moving to `push %rbp` / `pop %rbp`. But as far as I'm aware, `enter` stores the value of `%rsp` in `%rbp` and then additionally also decrements `%rsp` by the parameter specified

Comment: Yup.  It's still faster to `push`/`mov` / `sub $(8*10), %rsp`, which is why gcc/clang/icc do that.  Actually, it's faster to not make a stack frame at all, and just treat `rbp` as another call-preserved register.  (Make sure your compiler emits correct info in the `.eh_frame_hdr` section so debuggers and exception handlers can backtrace through your functions.)  See [Agner Fog's guides](http://agner.org/optimize/), and the other links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  Avoid `enter` like the plague unless you're strictly optimizing for code-size, not speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction `mov -48(%rbp), %r10` moves the value stored at `-48(%rbp)` into R10. This value can be anything since its taken from part of of the function's stack allocation (allocated with the ENTER instruction) and you never initialized it.

If you want to load the address of `-48(%rbp)` into a register you should use the LEA instruction:

```
lea -48(%rbp), %r10
```

You can also fold it into the instruction where you store RAX:

```
mov %rax, -48(%rbp, %r11, 8)
```